# Updating user profile efficiently

Tags: mysql, performance, apache2

Something just came to mind and I'd like to bounce it off:

Say you have a user profile, with 10 fields that the user can edit, and not all of them are required. When issuing update commands, is it more efficient to either:

A) Collect all of the fields, filled in or not, and issue one all encompassing update statement to the server's DB

or

B) Use client side validation to check to see which fields have been filled out or changed, and have a selection of SQL methods that only send and update these fields

or

C) Create groupings, like "updateRequiredFields(...) and updateExtraFields(...)", which would issue one smaller transfer if the changes only belong in one group, however two transfers if both are edited

General consensus? Clearly option B is the far more verbose approach, I'm just wondering if it's worth coding it all out or if it'll actually make a noticeable impact on the server (think "scaled for big data").

Comment: There is no big difference in all three methods you mentioned. As a good practice I would go with B since why update a field when it needs no updating?

Comment: The thing is, if the user updates say, 7/10 fields, that would be 7 trips to the database. I guess "smart" grouping (like, most commonly edited fields) might be a way to go?

Comment: See my answer to only update modified fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this on your DB update function:

```
public function updateFields(array $fields) {
   $updateQuery = array();
   foreach($fields as $fieldKey => $fieldValue) {
      //if $fieldValue is false, leave it unchanged
      if ($fieldValue !== false) {
         //NOTE: make sure you escape this or use PDO
         $updateQuery[] = $fieldKey . '=' . $fieldValue; 
      }
   }

   $query = 'UPDATE UserInfo SET ' . implode(",", $updateQuery) . ' WHERE ...';
}
```

You just need to build `$fields` array based on what was modified on client side and then pass in with either new value or with `false` if no change.

Comment: Wow, thank you for that!! I haven't worked with PHP long enough to know its built in functions like implode, I should brush up on the manual. Cool solution, I like the idea of dynamically generated SQL.